# RStudio does not launch from Anaconda

Tags: r, macos, anaconda, rstudio

I am running Mac OS 10.5.5 Catalina and I have installed Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12. I have been programming Python 3.7 scripts on it and everything works well.
I am now working on a project that uses R. On the Home tab of the Anaconda Navigator I have installed RStudio using the Install button. There is now a launch button under the RStudio icon. I click on the Launch button for RStudio and on the bottom right of the window a status indicates it is launching (for a few seconds). But nothing is ever launched. The RStudio program never opens up.
This is a new installation of Mac OS and it is a new installation of Anaconda (vintage June 10, 2020).Everything is up to date.
What can I do to get RStudio to open up from the Anaconda Navigator?

Comment: An additional hint I just discovered: I used the Anaconda Navigator menu and chose Quit Anaconda. I was then presented with a dialogue box that stated "There are some applications running. Please select the application you want to quit." The window has an RStudio as an option with a check box - indicating that is what I want to quit. The problem is there is no RStudio that I can see. Is it running in the background?

Comment: Rstudio is an IDE for R.  Try running Rstudio from the finder and skip attempting to loading in Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had a lot of problems for many months trying to use RStudio with Anaconda. There were so many problems (files were sometimes not saved, new R-Environments could not be created, RStudio could not be installed, packages were not correctly loaded etc.). I found also several others in the Internet who have experiencend similar problems. This is why I just installed RStudio and the base R directly without Anaconda and so far I have not had any problems with that.

Comment: This is the least helpful answer on this page (just putting it out there). If you need help, navigate to answer by @Wilis below!

Answer (score 6):

First you must create a new environment and select R. The default *base(root)* environment does not contain packages for R. See documentation at https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/
Be sure to remove R Studio from your base environment to free up space.

Comment: Good answer except I don't agree with *Be sure to remove R Studio from your base environment to free up space*. Generally I would tinker with the base environment as little as possible, and removing packages doesn't necessarily leave the env in the same state as before they were installed, so unless you are actually short of space I would leave it be (or reinstall Anaconda and re-create your envs...)

Comment: Thank you @Willis, you da best !